# Error running WSGI application in pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have this problem that I cant solve. After i done this in WSGI configuration file, when I go to my link I got this error. Anyone have some idea why?

```
    # +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

#
## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/Gvozdeni/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/Gvozdeni/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/Gvozdeni/django-deployment-example/learning_templates'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.chdir(path)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","learning_templates.settings")



import django
django.setup()

#
#os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
#
## then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Error:

```
2020-03-21 10:18:45,203: Error running WSGI application
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204:   File "/var/www/gvozdeni_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 52
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204: 
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204:     import django.setup()
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204: 
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204:                        ^
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204: 
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2020-03-21 10:18:45,204: ***************************************************
2020-03-21 10:18:45,205: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-03-21 10:18:45,205: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2020-03-21 10:18:45,205: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-03-21 10:18:45,205: ***************************************************
2020-03-21 10:23:13,457: Error running WSGI application
2020-03-21 10:23:13,457:   File "/var/www/gvozdeni_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 52
2020-03-21 10:23:13,458: 
2020-03-21 10:23:13,458:     import django.setup()
```

Comment: There seems to be a line `import django.setup()` with an obvious syntax error. But it is not present in the code you provided.

Comment: yea, I saw that and I dont know why it says import django.setup()
 
                                                                                     ^

Comment: If the file `gvozdeni_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` is not created by you, then it might be a glitch in the deployment platform and should be reported to their support.

Comment: That's not the code that is running. Have you reloaded your web app recently?

Comment: I solve it this way, @Klaus D. @Glenn

`code` os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'learning_templates.settings'
#

## then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
aplication=django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler() 
`code`